# Caliburn micro: how to organize screens

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to do a basic MVVM WPF app with the caliburn micro framework. My idea is to do the next structure:

Login dialog --> Main window with 3 buttons

--> 1. Screen with tabcontrol
--> 2. Simple screen

--> 3. Simple screen

I have read lots of articles about caliburn and I downloaded several samples, but I am still not sure wich are the steps to follow. I know that I have to create a WindowManager to manage the dialogs, popups, etc... and a conductor to manage the active screens. I achieved to open the main window menu right this:

Bootstrapper:

```
 public class Bootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    CompositionContainer _container;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {

    }


    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
        AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(_container);
        _container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service));
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service) : key;
        var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);
        if (exports.Count() > 0)
            return exports.First();
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instance of contract {0}.", contract));
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
 namespace MVVM_Caliburn_Sample1
{
    [Export(typeof(MainWindowViewModel))]
    public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainWindowViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            DisplayName = "Composition App";
            this.windowManager = windowManager;

        }

        public void OpenWin() {
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
            settings.PlacementTarget = GetView(null);
            windowManager.ShowDialog(new TabsViewModel(this.windowManager),null,settings);
        }

        public void OpenWin2() {
            var result = windowManager.ShowDialog(new TwoWindowViewModel(this.windowManager));
        }

        public void OpenWin3() { 
        //TO-DO
        }
    }
}
```

Screen with tabcontrol:

```
namespace MVVM_Caliburn_Sample1
{
    [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class TabsViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {

        readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TabsViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            DisplayName = "Tabs View";
            this.windowManager = windowManager;
            Items.Add(new TabOneViewModel());
            Items.Add(new TabTwoViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

TabOneViewModel:

```
namespace MVVM_Caliburn_Sample1
{
    [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class TabOneViewModel : Screen{

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TabOneViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "View #1";

        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing it right (opening the windows, the screens...)? The MainWindowViewModel must have its own conductor and the TabsViewModel another one for the tabs? I have to send the windowmanager like the example as I did? In general, how do you see this sample?

Sorry, I know I should be making mistakes but I'm learning.

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: You should consider using IoC to send the window manager to child VMs using dependency injection (and the same for the tab viewmodels), but otherwise it looks ok to me - conductors are there to conduct collections of screens. A tabcontrol is a collection of screens so nesting conductors is necessary with more complex layouts such as multiple screens, some of which contain tab controls.

Comment: Hi Charleh, could you explain me how to do this approach, please? Thank you for your quick response. I need more practice to pick up the caliburn.micro cheats and operations...

Comment: Just google dependency injection and inversion of control. There are examples on the codeplex site explaining how to use the container provided with caliburn micro (SimpleContainer). http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation - use that to manage dependencies and everything will become a little easier to structure

Comment: Charleh, I have printed the screen/conductors/composition documentation and I'm focusing the learning in this way to understand wich is the idea. Also I have been reading about this topics you propose. Thank you for your advices, I will keep working on it!